# How to update records laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have related tables in my database and i'm able to create a record with it's foreign keys successfully, but i cant figure out how to edit and update that record

Below is my store code that gets the inputs from my form:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    $account = new Account;
    $type = new Type;
    $agency = new Agency;
    $client = new Client;

    $agency->name = $request->input('agency_name');
    $agency->save();
    $type->name= $request->input('type_name');
    $type->save();
    $client->name= $request->input('client_name');
    $client->save();

    $account->client()->associate($client);
    $account->type()->associate($type);
    $account->agency()->associate($agency);

    $account->username = $request->username;
    $account->password = $request->password;
    $account->save();

    return redirect('accounts');
    }
```

The above stores the record successfully, but i dont know how to edit it, the below pulls the account data in my edit fields but doenst show the account_id field, type_id and client_id fields they are blank:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account=Account::find($id);
    return view('accounts.edit',compact('account'));
}
```

my update code, what goes here?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // ???
    return redirect('accounts');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, you should change your store function like this -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $account = new Account;

    $type = Type::whereName($request->type_name);
    if (!is_null($type)) {
        $type = $type->first();
    }else{
        $type = Type::create(['name' => $request->type_name]);
    }
    $agency = Agency::whereName($request->agency_name);
    if (!is_null($agency)) {
        $agency = $agency->first();
    }else{
        $agency = Agency::create(['name' => $request->agency_name]);
    }
    $client = Client::whereName($request->client_name);
    if (!is_null($client)) {
        $client = $client->first();
    }else{
        $client = Agency::create(['name' => $request->client_name]);
    }

    $account->client()->associate($client);
    $account->type()->associate($type);
    $account->agency()->associate($agency);

    $account->site_url = $request->site_url;
    $account->login_url = $request->login_url;
    $account->username = $request->username;
    $account->password = $request->password;
    $account->server_ip = $request->server_ip;
    $account->database = $request->database;
    $account->other = $request->other;
    $account->save();
    return redirect('accounts');
}
```

> Now, once you add an account and open the edit form, you should be able to see the **type**, **agency** & **client**.

As for the update method, you need to do something like this (assuming you're passing in *agency*, *type* & *client* -

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);
    $type = Type::whereName($request->type['name']);
    if (!is_null($type)) {
        $type = $type->first();
    }else{
        $type = Type::create(['name' => $request->type['name']]);
    }
    $agency = Agency::whereName($request->agency['name']);
    if (!is_null($agency)) {
        $agency = $agency->first();
    }else{
        $agency = Agency::create(['name' => $request->agency['name']]);
    }
    $client = Client::whereName($request->client['name']);
    if (!is_null($client)) {
        $client = $client->first();
    }else{
        $client = Agency::create(['name' => $request->client['name']]);
    }

    $account->client()->associate($client);
    $account->type()->associate($type);
    $account->agency()->associate($agency);

    $account->site_url = $request->site_url;
    $account->login_url = $request->login_url;
    $account->username = $request->username;
    $account->password = $request->password;
    $account->server_ip = $request->server_ip;
    $account->database = $request->database;
    $account->other = $request->other;
    $account->save();

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Account successfully updated');
    return redirect('accounts');
}
```

Comment: This breaks my store method, which was working, and my update method now gives "FatalErrorException in AccountsController.php line 150:
Call to a member function save() on null"

Comment: what did you do in your store method, I hope you didn't just copy and paste it blind?

Comment: I put the entire function in now, so that you can copy and paste it.. but how does your store method break though? what is the error?

Comment: Your store give this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`accounts`, CONSTRAINT `accounts_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `accounts` (`username`, `password`) values (sdasdfasdf, sdasdfasdf))

Comment: They way i have it in OP works just fine for storing data. Your update record gives this error " FatalErrorException in AccountsController.php line 149:
Call to a member function save() on null"

Comment: @Devnoob the store method only works for the username and password, and since the OP has not enabled mass assignment (or at least not using it), the respective foreign keys are not being stored.. We need to solve that first.

Comment: if i edit the record in a form and use agency_id instead of agency_name (which shows blank), i see the foreign key or id for that particular account(username, password)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113973/discussion-between-atefth-and-devnoob).